# Javascript automate onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to automate clicking a few links on a webpage

For example, in Google Chrome if I type `Javascript:setDisplayType('source');` then it runs the function in the html defined as

```
    <input type="radio" name="DisplayType" value="source" 
onclick="setDisplayType('source');">
```

So far so good. However, I'm unsure about how to do the same with the following

```
<td id="4124321351_U923" class="o bgc b" onclick="s(this,'329803656','40745906','9/2');b(this,'5.5','5.5');">5.5</td>
```

I've tried the following without success

Javascript:s(this,'329803656','40745906','9/2');

Javascript:b(this,'5.5','5.5');

Javascript:s(this,'329803656','40745906','9/2');b(this,'5.5','5.5');

Please can someone explain why it's not working and how to fire this onclick event using a similar method?

Comment: Have you tried "javascript:s(...);"

Can you please provide a JSFiddle example?

Comment: You have function setDisplayType, what is b and s ? sorry, if I am not getting the right.

Comment: `document.getElementById('4124321351_U923').click()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're not using JQuery or similar, then something like:

```
document.getElementById("4124321351_U923").click();
```

might work.  In short, your examples above don't work because the 'this' magic variable needs to be initialised to point to the link being clicked.  You could either try to initiate a *click* event on the element (as per my example) or you could manually grab a reference to the link, and pass that in instead of *this*

Comment: I would suggest this, instead of @MuthuKamaran's answer.

Comment: I think I prefer this method as it's much simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Problem is with `this` argument because it's not called from the element and you called it outside.
`Javascript:s(this,'329803656','40745906','9/2');`

Try proving a proper argument like this,
`Javascript:s(document.getElementById('4124321351_U923'),'329803656','40745906','9/2');`